# Memory leak in UITableView when scrolled on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks

For each time UITableview is scrolled, there is a memory leak of 48 bytes.
Responsible library : libsystem_c.dylib
Responsible frame : strdup.

This is observed only on iOS 5.1 and not on earlier versions.
Did anyone else faced the same? Is this a bug in iOS 5.1?

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"fontSelectionCell"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [cellIdentifier release];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }       

    cell.textLabel.text = [fontNameList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];

    if ([fontName isEqualToString:cell.textLabel.text])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: show some code may be? cellForRowAtIndexPath: method would be most interesting... also do you use ARC in your project?

Comment: did you use the default implementation with no custom code? is it leaking, or will the memory just be cleared later (because of autoreleased objects).

Comment: @jaydee3, I tested a simple application with basic table view but the memory leak is still there.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue, in some rare instances when scrolled all the way up and bouncing and then all the way bottom it causes several leaks, and at one point it killed the app with SIGKILL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having this issue that was already report on iOS 5.1. I am having that myself too. At the moment I wasn't able to find the link in apple's forums concerning this issue.

Comment: I also came across few references stating that it is a known issue in iOS 5.1  One such ref: http://openradar.appspot.com/11081198

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to the way you are handling the cell identifier. I'm actually surprised it does not crash for you, since you release `cellIndentifier` but then reference it when creating a new cell (i.e. when a cell wasn't return for reuse from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`).

The standard/accepted way to use a cell identifier is to use a static (because it won't ever change, and it will only be alloc-ed once and not potentially 100s of times since `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called constantly when scrolling a table). This would make your code much more efficient.

i.e.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"fontSelectionCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }   

   ...
}
```

Could you try changing `cellIdentifier` and see if you still get the leak?

Comment: Hi, I tried with static NSString for cellIdentifier but still getting the same memory leak when tableView is scrolled.

Comment: do you see which class/type is leaking? what does instruments display?